# Getting Cisco UCS Server's CPU Serial Numbers

Tags: cisco, central-processing-unit, licensing, cisco-ucs

I have a Cisco UCS C240 M3S server with dual CPU failure under warranty. I am trying to find both CPU serial numbers to complete the RMA request, however cannot find any serial numbers. I have tried to find them in CIMC running the following:

```
scope server 8
scope cpu 1
show detail
scope cpu 2
show detail
```

I have also looked under Cisco UCS Manager under the server's inventory tab and selected CPUs, but there is not a serial number listed. Are the serial numbers on the physical blade or is there somewhere else I should look?

Comment: No an answer but I can't believe they're asking for the SN's - I'm a HP client and we've had all sorts of kit break but never been asked for a CPU serial number - seems a bit unnecessary. Either way if there's no way to get the SN via software you're going to have to open up the box and read them off the package - including removing and heatsink/cooling.

Comment: I was afraid of this... I agree. It seems completely unnecessary and a total pain in the butt. Plus that means I have to go on-site to get this information. Dang dang double dang.

Comment: Tell them to sod off, why should it be your problem - speak to your account manager if needed - I'm a big fan of dealing with problems as non-technically as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your warranty should be tied to the chassis of the server. [Just like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/641612/is-disk-serial-readable-from-supermicro-chassis/641619#641619), you should never have to give an individual component's serial number for support. This is especially true for a non-serviceable/non-accessible part like a CPU.

Comment: I agree. It shouldn't, but the tech specifically asked for the device model AND serial number for all CPU's. I already gave the tech the serial number to the server so maybe that will be good enough. We'll see... Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ask for a second-opinion or try to get another tech on the line. It's not reasonable for them to expect that you can access that information without downtime.

Comment: It's probably a tech who uses the word "CPU" to mean "computer case"... as many laymen do.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Ewwhite in that the warranty is tied to the chassis of the server.

The CPU serial number is inaccessible without physically looking at from what I can gather via the CIMC.

Even getting a tech support dump:

[image]

the corresponding dump tar only contains the same data the GUI contains.  There's nothing in any of the files from a search regarding serial numbers of the CPUs themselves.

But again, if it's under warranty call your Account Manager and let them know the grief you are experiencing...then tell them to send a Cisco field rep onsite at that location.